# variable point equals element in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char x[] = "hello";
    char *y = "world";
    *y = x[1];
    printf("%s", y);

return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please help me understand why this code will not compile?

Comment: have you heard about the `\0` character? Also - if the program does not compile, there should be error messages. Read them and if you dont understand them - google is your friend

Comment: It will compile, but likely crash on the line `*y = x[1];`.

Comment: why does it crash at *y = x[1]  - that is what I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

String literals are immutable in C. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undeﬁned**.

You could use an array initialized by the sting literal instead of the string literal itself. For example

```
char x[] = "hello";
char y[] = "world";
*y = x[1];
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also if you are compiling the program as a C++ program then the compiler also can issue an error for the statement

```
char *y = "world";
```

because in C++ (opposite to C) string literals have types of constant character arrays. So in this case the valid declaration is

```
const char *y = "world";
```

Comment: i thought the problem was with with x[] at first.
your explanation makes sense
thank you

Comment: is the fact that *y is a pointer have anything to do with the complie error?

Comment: @Rgoat It seems that the compiler is able to recognize that you are trying to modify the string literal "world" using the pointer y that points to the string literal.

Comment: thanks Vlad that makes sense. I don't assume the variable 'y' has anything to do with *y? or are they unrelated at all?

Comment: @Rgoat I am sorry I have not understood what you are asking.

Comment: what I meant to say was, because there is no variable called 'y' and there is a variable called *y, isn't there supposed to be a variable called 'y' before *y can exist? i hope this makes sense what I am asking

Comment: @Rgoat There is declared one variable y that has a pointer type. In this expression *y the pointer is dereferenced to access the memory it points to..

Answer (score 1):

> why does it crash at *y = x[1] - that is what I don't understand

It crashes because you are trying to write a character 'e' at a memory location which is read-only. This read-only memory location is the one pointed to by the pointer `y`.

**How did `y` end up pointing to a `read-only` memory location?**

You instructed it by writing the line `char *y = "world";`.

This is a two-step process. First a string literal "world" is created in a read-only memory area. String literals are always created in read-only memory area. Secondly, a pointer `y` is created which points to this read only memory.

**What's the fix for this problem?**

Use an array instead of a pointer.

Instead of

`char *y = "world";`

Use

`char y[] = "world";`

**Why does it work over the pointer?**

Here it is a 3 step process. First, a string literal "world" is created in the readonly memory section. Secondly, a new memory of 6 bytes is created in stack. Thirdly, charaters 'w', 'o','r','l','d','\0' are copied from the read-only memory containing literal, to this memory on stack which is rewritable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing :

```
char x[] = "hello";
char *y = "world";
    *y = x[1];
printf("%s", y);
```

Here it will give compile time error because of line :  `*y = x[1];` , you can check it by commenting this line, further if now you will print y then you will get y as world.

> Notice : There is no error in `char *y = "world"`

For the task you want , you can write :

```
char *y ;
y = & x[1];    // but here y become "ello" as it will read upto a '\0'
```

Now, here y is having address of x[1].

Here,  `char x[] = "hello"` , x is a pointer to character type location so implicitly it work as [char x[] = "hello as *(x) = "world"],  so it will work fine.

Btw if you want only 2nd character of x in y, then write :

```
char x[] = "hello";
char y ;
y = x[1];
printf("%c", y);  // y = e
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes when you are trying to write into a so-called constant area, which is what "world" is.  What you need to do is something like this:

```
int main() {
    char x[] = "hello";
    char *y;
    y = strdup("world");
    *y = x[1];
    printf("%s\n", y);
    free(y);
    return 0;
}
```